# What will be the Validation function to check the first name contains letters only?(Angular 2+)

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5

I want to write a function and use it in html page in an Angular project..The input field First Name should have letters only and that will be checked when the focus shifted to another input field only. For example  if First-Name is 123 given by the user and then focus is shifted to last-name then an error message like "should not be number" will be shown.User can input numbers but while shifting to another input field then only the error will be shown.

typescript code:

```
 checkValidation(event){
        this.firstnameValid=true;
        if(event.which !=8 && event.which !=9){
          //var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
          var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
          if (!regex.test(event.key)) 
             {
               event.preventDefault();
              this.firstnameValid=false
             }
      }
```

html code:

```
<div class="row noMargin inputGroup">
          <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <p >First Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></p>
            <div class="row noMargin relative">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control transparentInput" [(ngModel)]="applicant.firstName" (keydown)="checkValidation($event)" name="FstName1" #FstName="ngModel"  required >
              <div *ngIf="FstName.invalid && (FstName.dirty || FstName.touched || AddApplicantForm.submitted )" class="errMsg">
                <span *ngIf="FstName.errors.pattern">shouldn't be number</span>
                <div *ngIf="!firstnameValid">
                      First name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try (change) instead (keydown).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **(blur)** event :

```
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control transparentInput" [(ngModel)]="applicant.firstName" (blur)="checkValidation($event)" name="FstName1" #FstName="ngModel"  required >
```

and for checking the value of the input use **event.target.value**

```
if (!regex.test(event.target.value)) 
         {
           event.preventDefault();
          this.firstnameValid=false

         }
```